# Remove repeating words in column, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have got pandas DataFrame as below:

| First Column | Second Column |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | Dog is good |
| Big Cat | Big cat is here |
| Fat rat | Fat rat is there |
| Pink tree | Pink tree means love |

I want to remove repeating word in second column based on first column. My desired output is:

| First Column | Second Column |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | is good |
| Big Cat | is here |
| Fat rat | is there |
| Pink tree | means love |

How can i achieve it?

I have looked around here, but could not find solution which would suite me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using row-wise `apply` with `axis=1`:

```
df['Second Column'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Second Column'].lower().replace(x['First Column'].lower(), ''), axis=1)
```

---

```
>>> df
  First Column Second Column
0          Dog       is good
1      Big Cat       is here
2      Fat rat      is there
3    Pink tree    means love
>>>
```